# Highlight stack plot region with matplotlib

Tags: matplotlib

I would like to highlight a region of one stack in a stackplot, for example the region 4-5 on the x-axis for `B` only with another color or hashes:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
x = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
y1 = [1, 1, 2, 3, 5]
y2 = [0, 4, 2, 6, 8]

labels = ['A', 'B']

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.stackplot(x, y1, y2, labels=labels)
ax.legend()
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Manually added polygons. This can be both colored and hatched at the same time.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.patches as patches

x = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
y1 = [1, 1, 2, 3, 5]
y2 = [0, 4, 2, 6, 8]

labels = ['A', 'B']

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.stackplot(x, y1, y2, labels=labels)

p = patches.Polygon(((4.0, 3.0),(5.0,4.0),(5.0,13.0),(4.0,9.0)), fc='g', hatch='x')
ax.add_patch(p)

ax.legend()
```

[image]